# When load image using Picasso its showing blur

Tags: android, image, picasso, blur

In my Android activity, I am loading an image in an `ImageView` using Picasso in my layout. The problem is that the image is showing as blurred. I have tried another image loader like Glide but I'm still getting blurred image. I have tried  this  code:

```
   Picasso.with(this).load(ServiceConstant.BASE_URL_IMAGE + distributor_large_image)
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.placeholder_banner)
                    .into(img_distributor, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            img_distributor.startAnimation(scaleUp);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
```

and the url of image is `http://tgpsf.progressivecoders.com/resources/images/distributor/thumb/15205922045aa2654c74bd2.jpg`

and my layout  imageview  is

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_distributor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/placeholder_banner" />
```

Please can anyone help me to resolve my problem?

Comment: Try to remove property android:scaleType="centerCrop" . its working

Comment: can you post your animation which is used for " img_distributor.startAnimation(scaleUp);" ?  remove animation and check it

Comment: Make sure you are not setting custom height & width to `imageview` in your activity, also remove `centerCrop` from your xml file, also make sure your scale up animation is not cutting / cropping the image

Comment: i have tried all this  above , but still not find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the URL you provided it may be the case that you are using too `small image` or `lower quality` with bigger imageview.
so that may be the issue. Try using other Image URL with better resolution/quality in order to test.

You can also use `resize property` (along with your desired parameters) of Picasso Lib. for quick loading of large images.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem.
You can use something like this..

```html
String url = "your url for the image here!!";
Picasso.get()
       .load(url)
       .into(name of the imageview);
```

This might help you..